# How to get a result from a query without the tag "stdClass Object" in Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, casting, laravel

I'm using Laravel v4.0 with MySQL. I'm making queries with Query Builder to retrieve the information to be managed by a controller. The problem is the result of any query contains a tag named **stdClass Object**:

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [srv_codctrl] => KIRAVA ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [srv_codctrl] => KIRBAS ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [srv_codctrl] => KIRMAN ) )
```

I can manipulate the data with that format casting it to an array but I think there should be a way to get the result without that tag.

Anyone knows a solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the PDO Fetch style in `app/config/database.php` to `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC`:

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| PDO Fetch Style
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| By default, database results will be returned as instances of the PHP
| stdClass object; however, you may desire to retrieve records in an
| array format for simplicity. Here you can tweak the fetch style.
|
*/

'fetch' => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC
```

Here's more on [PDO Fetch style](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php#refsect1-pdostatement.fetch-parameters).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the array above is in a variable called array:

```
foreach($array as $obj)
{
    echo $obj->srv_codctrl;
}
```

or

```
echo $array[0]->srv_codctrl;
```